# How stable and mature is Boo?

Tags: boo

I had a look at Boo and it looks pretty awesome! I'm just curious about how stable it is at this stage? I mean, would you consider using it in real live production code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been production quality for several years now. Lots of people are using it, for example through the [Brail view engine](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/documentation/trunk/viewengines/brail/index.html), [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/unity/features/scripting.html) and [Binsor](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/16/IntroductingBinsorTheBooDSLForWindsor.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Rodrigo has stated that Boo will be at 1.0 [when it can be written in Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/FAQ) (last FAQ item). It is currently at 0.9.3.  One of the items to be included before the 1.0 release, according to the bug/issue tracker, is Dynamic Object from .Net 4.0, but the matter may be up in the air based on [Rodrigo's reply to questions about Net 4.0 features](http://groups.google.com/group/boolang/browse_thread/thread/667c076ebaeddc21/e6e133e4bed3c71a?lnk=gst&q=net+4.0#e6e133e4bed3c71a).

Comment: Isn't IQuackFu essentially DynamicObject?  I'm not sure there's much work they need to do to implement that.

Comment: Yes, Rodrigo sees it as a matter of changing over the dynamic dispatch implementation.  He's looking for someone to step up and do it if you're interested. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually 1.0 yet (almost). That's what they're using as a guage or production readiness I believe.